# How to use TagLib# to gain VideoHeader information from Video Files

Tags: c#, header, mpeg, frame-rate, taglib-sharp

I am creating a program to access information on different types of files, I have so far been successful mostly with MP3 files and am now working on the video MPG etc types.

So far I have been able to obtain Video Title, Year, Duration, Genre, video height and width with little effort and now I am attempting to access the slightly more difficult aspects from the VideoHeader section of TagLib.

This is the code I have managed to obtain from finding something about AudioHeaders on here but it didnt work:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.Mpeg.File.Create(GetMPG.FileName);

foreach(ICodec codec in f.Properties.Codecs){
  TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader G = (TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader) codec;
  MPGbps.Text = G.VideoFrameRate.ToString();
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

My new current code:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(GetMPG.FileName);
foreach(ICodec codec in f.Properties.Codecs){
  TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader G = (TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader) codec;
  if (G != null)
    {
      MPGbps.Text = G.VideoFrameRate.ToString();
    }
}
```

This has ended in the error:

### Error 2   Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader' and '< null >'

note: added spaces in final null as it didn't show up in the post otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video files have multiple codecs, an audio and a video one.  What's happening with your code is that in one iteration of the loop, codec is not a VideoHeader meaning G is not set correctly. I'm not sure if this triggers an exception or if G is set to an empty VideoHeader.

The below code should work:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(GetMPG.FileName);

foreach(ICodec codec in f.Properties.Codecs){
  if(codec is TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader) {
    TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader G = (TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader) codec;
    MPGbps.Text = G.VideoFrameRate.ToString();
  }
}
```

Also, you should be using `TagLib.File.Create` instead. It is a static factory method.

**Update**

Beyond the above initial issue where `codec` was being cast as the wrong type, there was the issue that the file was not a MPEG and did not actually contain a `TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader` and had a `TagLib.Riff.BitmapInfoHeader` instead.  Beyond the basic properties guaranteed by `TagLib.IVideoCodec`, the details provided by individual file formats varies widely on a case by case basis.  It is important to know what file types are in scope, what features you want to detect, and extract video details as available.

Comment: I shall investigate this when on the pc next

Comment: Error 1 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TagLib.Mpeg.VideoHeader' and '<null>'

Comment: Hmm... `VideoHeader` is a struct so we'll have to use is.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: ok so i have reduced the code testing down to line running. the code executes perfectly fine but there is no response from any video file i try, it executes the if twice but never gets to the code to set the data

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Visual Studio.  You could inject debug breakpoints in the function to see if `codec` is indeed a `VideoHeader` and if so, what the values are.

Comment: i didnt check that, i have the breakpoints in already just forgot to check the values

Comment: What type does the debugger report for f? It sounds like you have an AVI or something similar.

Comment: its reporting taglib.riff.file it is an avi and on the explorer it does not show FPS so i assume that type of file is not supported. is there a calculation i can use?

Comment: Unfortunately, Riff files are simple wrappers holding other media with an unlimited possibility for the actual format. All we can really tell without advanced information is width and height. To get a feel for how many different video formats are supported, see https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/master/src/TagLib/Riff/BitmapInfoHeader.cs#L338

Comment: thanks for your help, it helped getting the code running and thats what i was after.